# Working with Keras on Python: how do I switch between floating point and fixed point?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, keras, fixed-point

I am playing around with Keras to build neural networks.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils import np_utils
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

data = pd.read_csv('IRIS.csv')
x = data.values[:,0:4].astype('float32')
y = data.values[:,4]
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y)
y = encoder.transform(y)
y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
y = y.astype('float32')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(4, input_dim = 4, init = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, init = 'normal', activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y, nb_epoch = 200, batch_size = 5)
score = model.evaluate(x,y)
print(score)
```

It works well with float32. I want to see if it will work better with fixed point or dynamic fixed point. How do I change the number representation?

This is what i've worked with

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.utils import np_utils
import numpy as np
from decimal import *
(x, y), (X, Y) = mnist.load_data()
num = x.shape[1] * x.shape[2]
getcontext().prec = 5
x = x.reshape(x.shape[0],x.shape[1]*x.shape[2]).astype(np.dtype(Decimal))
X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],X.shape[1]*X.shape[2]).astype(np.dtype(Decimal))

x = x/Decimal(255)
X = X/Decimal(255)

y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(Y)

classes = y.shape[1]

def calc():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(num, input_dim = num, init = 'normal', activation = 'relu'))
    model.add(Dense(classes, init = 'normal', activation = 'softmax'))
    model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer = 'adam', metrics = ['accuracy'])
    return model

model = calc()
model.fit(x, y, validation_data=(X, Y), epochs=10, batch_size=200,
    verbose=2)
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: ", scores)
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe, that this feature exists in Keras or in the backend that you use?

Comment: I want to change the format of the input to the neural network. Nothing to do with the backend right?

Comment: Well, the backend does the actual computations. Therefore it should support the format aswell. A quick search on the keras documentation for 'fixed point' gave no results. That's why I would assume it is not supported and wondered why you would think it is?

Comment: I tried using the Decimal library, it is working. But Im not sure if Im working with fixed point or just a float with lower precision

Comment: Can you provide an example of this? Deep Learning libraries use some highly optimized numerical libraries for the actual computations. And highly optimized usually means also not very flexible. That's why I doubt that you can just plug in some third party library and get the results you want.

Comment: @sietschie I have updated the question